# Redux: How to update a single property of an object

Tags: redux, react-redux

my current state is an object like this

```
{active: true, dateAdded: "02-07-2019", endEpoch: "02-07-2019", name: "pics"}
```

My reducer

```
 export default (state = initial_state, actions) => {
    switch (actions.type) {
        case SUBREDDIT_SELECTED:
            {
                return { ...state,
                    selected_sub: actions.payload
                }
            }
            break;
        case EPOCH_CHANGED:
            {
                return { ...state,
                    selected_sub: actions.payload
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

How do I update the endEpoch property of the state?

Answer (score 0):

You already do what you want. To update `endEpoch` do

```
    case EPOCH_CHANGED:
        {
            return { ...state,
                endEpoch: actions.payload
            }
        }
        break;
```

Spreading `state` leaves all it props in place. And changes `endEpoch`.